# Show and Hide Javascript HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm doing my designer-portfolio in html and I wanted to have a menu that only shows when this character is pressed...

But I'm new on programming and my codes are very simple, so I'm using this:

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if(e.style.visibility == 'hidden')
      e.style.visibility = 'visible';
  else
      e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function untoggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if(e.style.visibility == 'visible')
      e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  else
      e.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```html
<div id="openmenu" style="visibility: visible;" onclick="toggle_visibility('menu'); onclick=toggle_visibility('closemenu');">openmenu</div>
    
<div id="closemenu" style="visibility: hidden;" onclick="untoggle_visibility('menu'); onclick=untoggle_visibility('closemenu');">closemenu</div>
    
<div id="menu" style="visibility: hidden;">...</div>
```

The problem is it only works once...

When I click on `#openmenu` it shows the `#menu` and the `#closemenu`, and when I click on `#closemenu` it hiddes the `#menu` and the `#closemenu`.

BUT it only works once, so if I press `#openmenu` after `#closemenu`, it won't work...

Comment: Use css display property

display:none

Comment: `onclick="toggle_visibility('menu'); onclick=toggle_visibility('closemenu');"` make no sense. And why have two function that do the same thing?

Comment: "toggle" is a term for switching between two states, as you've aptly done in your `toggle_visibility` function. "untoggle" doesn't make sense, since you are still switching between the same states. So, remove the `untoggle_visibility` function and references to it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong.

```
onclick="toggle_visibility('menu'); onclick=toggle_visibility('closemenu');"
```

So what happens with the above code is it runs once. And when it runs it reassigns onclick because you have onclick=functionCall

So after it runs you basically have `<div onclick=undefined>` because the function did not run.

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.visibility == 'hidden')
    e.style.visibility = 'visible';
  else
    e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function untoggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.visibility == 'visible')
    e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  else
    e.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```html
<div id="openmenu" style="visibility: visible;" onclick="toggle_visibility('menu');toggle_visibility('closemenu');">openmenu</div>

<div id="closemenu" style="visibility: hidden;" onclick="untoggle_visibility('menu');untoggle_visibility('closemenu');">closemenu</div>

<div id="menu" style="visibility: hidden;">...</div>
```

How would most people code it? By toggling a class.

```js
function toggle_visibility(ids) {
  ids.forEach( function (id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    elem.classList.toggle('visibilityHidden')
  })
}
```

```css
.visibilityHidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* use hidden if you do not want it to take up space */
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="openmenu" onclick="toggle_visibility(['menu','openmenu','closemenu']);">openmenu</div>

<div id="closemenu" class="visibilityHidden" onclick="toggle_visibility(['menu','openmenu','closemenu']);">closemenu</div>

<div id="menu" class="visibilityHidden">...</div>
```

Most developers would not use inline event handlers either, but that is a different question.